Read and inject SQL Instrunction in a PICO H
I am trying to create a pico code that read from a database file ".db", I have tried to install many packages

usqlite
SQL
sql30

none of them have worked, unfortunately, as they require the sqlite3 package, and I didn't know how to download it or use it
I have a PICO H RP2040
if someone could please provide a detailed explanation, on how to download it, to how to use it, I would be grateful

RP204 is a microcontroller, not a computer with an OS.

@TheImpaler is there any alternatives for the pico that works with pico??
